# Using AVAudioPlayer play in for

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, avaudioplayer

How I can use play sound in cycle example for

when i try to use like

```
..
mySound.numberOfLoops = 1; // or 0 (if -1 play infinitely)
..
    for ... 
    {
    ///....
      if .... {
         //...
        [mySound play]; 
    }
```

only one play time

Comment: Are you trying to play a sample again and again monophonically (just one playing at a time) or are you trying to play the same sample polyphonically (multiple samples playing concurrently)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean that you want to play multiple sounds at the same time or if you want to play the sound forever. To play the sound forever set the value of mySound.numberOfLoops to -1. If you want to play multiple sounds you have to allocate new AVAudioPlayers every time. In order to do this you could allocate a new one at the beggining of the if expression, although it might be difficult to stop the sounds whenever you want.